# What are the pros and cons of using Stream sorting over Collections sorting in Java?

Tags: java, list, sorting, java-8, java-stream

Lets say I have a pojo Model as:

```
class Model{
      String id;
      String name;
}
```

List in Java, and I want to sort an already filled list List models.
For now, I'm considering two options:

1. Using Colletions.List :

   `models.sort(.sort(Comparator.comparing(Model::getId)))`
2. Using sorted function of Java8 Stream API:

   `models..stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Model::getId)).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Can anyone please explain pros and cons of using Method 2 over Method 1?

Comment: Well, you could have a look at it yourself but criteria I'd consider would include memory (probably not top priority), performance (also not top prio), readability (how easy is it for devs to read and understand the code?), safety (how easy is it to make errors?), availability (not important if you'll always run on Java 8+). Just considering readability I'd opt for method 1, as for safety I'd opt for method 2 since it will create a new list and thus won't "accidentally" sort a list you'd not want sorted in another place.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for quick comment.I can live with memory, readability, availability for now but performance is a major consideration.

Comment: Do you work with very large lists? Otherwise performance is nothing to worry about. Using parallel sorting can improve performance if the lists are huge.

Comment: @Jack Flamp Yes my data is in order of >10,000 normally(60% of time). But in case of boundry cases it comes down to <10(40% of time). This is the reason why i need a way to handle both efficiently.

Comment: ok, so one obvious difference would be that you can sort in parallel using streams (multiple threads and multiple cores).

Comment: @Jack Flamp Yeah, that is a good criterion indeed. Not needing to write any parallelization code is a good plus point.

Comment: @Jack Flamp: there is [`Arrays.parallelSort(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#parallelSort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-), so this does not necessarily need the Stream API.

Comment: @Holger that's right. a nice feature

Answer (score 4):

I believe the biggest difference is that if you use list.sort() it actually sorts the list. If you use list.stream().sorted() that returns a sorted list but doesn't actually sort the list you start from. There might be cases for both - depending on what you prefer.

Comment: I like the argument, especially if the source you are streaming from is immutable.

Comment: @Eugene: sure, but if all you want is a new sorted list, using `List<ElementType> newList = new ArrayList<>(oldList); newList.sort(comparator);` is still more efficient than using the Stream API…

Comment: @Holger the stream API got so deep under my skin that I don't find it as such anymore... can't tell if this is a good thing though

Comment: @Eugene: this is only about the special case of streaming a Collection, doing at most a single op not changing the element type, followed by collecting into a standard Collection, possibly of the same type as the starting point.